# AppleScript - Pull text fields from a webpage, and compile them in a text document

Tags: applescript

I'm trying to compose AppleScript to open a specific page, locate 10 or so different fields of text, take that text to a separate document(i.e notes).

I've seen, for what I think to be, much more advance AppleScript coding out there, so I hope this is possible. If you have an alternative, im all ears. Even any documentation that goes over said instructions, would be great.

So if I go to the site, I can see the left most field of text, titled "Network Stats." How can I have the AppleScript take some of this text and paste it into a doc.

I hope to be able to copy/past in a text doc(i.e notes):

Dollars: $27.3 Trillion in Market Cap Field Types: 98% of the Energy... etc

```
-- Look at Safari 
tell application "Safari" 
    open location "https://www.nyse.com/network" 
    delay 2 
    -- Locate Fields 
    delay 3 
    -- Paste Text 
    delay 3 
end tell
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a string point: It reads the text with `curl` and parses it with `text item delimiters` and Regular Expression

```
use AppleScript version "2.4" -- Yosemite (10.10) or later
use framework "Foundation"
use scripting additions

set nyseSource to do shell script "curl https://www.nyse.com/network"
set {TID, text item delimiters} to {text item delimiters, "<ul class=\"resources-list\">" & return & space}
set resourcesList to text item 2 of nyseSource
set text item delimiters to "</ul>"
set resourcesList to text item 1 of resourcesList
set text item delimiters to TID
set nsResourcesList to current application's NSString's stringWithString:resourcesList
set trimmedString to (nsResourcesList's stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:"</?li>" withString:"" options:(current application's NSRegularExpressionSearch) range:{location:0, |length|:(count resourcesList)}) as text
```

Comment: At first this was gibberish, but after some digging and researching working examples, this made sense. Really appreciate the support. I'll let you know if I get it to work.